# ng-submit doesn't work in form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend, mean-stack

I've reviewed every question concerning ng-submit, but I still can't get it to work. On submit, it should call the publish() function in the post controller. For the purposes of sharing it on SO, I have only included a console.log() within the function. However, I have another button below, which when clicked, will call the publish function and console.log the message into the Chrome console.

post.html

```
<form ng-submit="post.publish()">
  <div class="form-input-body">
    <textarea ng-model="post.postData.body"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Publish</button> // This doesn't call the function
</form>
<button type ng-click="post.publish()"> // This calls the function
```

postController.js

```
angular.module('postCreateCtrl', ['postCreateService'])
    .controller('postCreateController', function(PostCreate) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.publish = function() {
            console.log("This doesn't work");
        };

    });
```

app.js (I have edited some of the code out)

```
angular.module('myApp',

[
    ...

    'postCreateController',
    'postCreateService'
]);
```

app.routes.js

```
angular.module('app.routes', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      ...

      .state('postCreate', {
        url: '/posts/create',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/postCreate/post.html',
        controller: 'postCreateController',
        controllerAs: 'post'
      });

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

Comment: You should just be able to call `publish()` rather than `post.publish()`

Comment: I've tested here and it is working normaly, can you show a bit more of the code?

Comment: I am sure the controller is being used since it will call the function when I'm not using the form.

Comment: I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BhxZUUk1p5C5COoGFsny?p=preview) to try to recreate your issue.  This works perfectly, once I fixed the name of the module (and removed the service reference, since it wasn't necessary to prove functionality).  There may be something you haven't shown yet in your code interfering, but it's clearly not an issue with the function, controller, or `ng-submit` you have presented here.

Comment: Any idea what could possibly be interfering?

Comment: For now, I'm just going to use ng-click to grab the values. Is there anything wrong with this approach that I should know about?

Comment: @JonRoby  maybe it has to do with the version? What angular version you got?